Javafx - How can I add a label to XYChart.data
I'm trying to build a from-scratch gantt diagram using JavaFX for machines monitoring using my own extension of XYChart. Each machine is represented by an instance of XYChart.Series like this :
series1 = new XYChart.Series();
and instances of XYChart.data representing the requested tasks for the machine are added to this series :
       series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0, machine, new GanttChart.ExtraData( 1, "status-red")));
How can I add labels to these instances of XYChart.Data ?
Thanks.

The examples here and here use positioning in a layout pane.

You can invoke setNode on the XYChart.Data to add an arbitrary node to the data.
XYChart.Data<String, Number> data =  new XYChart.Data<>(
        s,
        75
);

data.setNode(new Label(s));

Example
This chart adds a label to each data value in the form:
xValue : yValue


In the example, I wrap the label for the node in a StackPane because otherwise the label's style class is overwritten by the internal XYChart implementation.
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class LabeledLettergramApp extends Application {

    private static final String CSS_DATA_URL_TYPE = "data:text/css,";
    private static final String CSS = CSS_DATA_URL_TYPE + """
            .chart {
                -fx-border-color: purple;
            }
            .data-label {
                -fx-text-fill: antiquewhite;
                -fx-font-size: 22px;
                -fx-alignment: center;
            }
            """;

    private static final String CHART_STYLE = "chart";
    private static final String DATA_LABEL_STYLE = "data-label";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        String[] alphabet = "ABCDEFG".split("");

        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
        for (String s : alphabet) {
            series.getData().add(
                    createData(s)
            );
        }

        BarChart<String, Number> barChart = new BarChart<>(
                new CategoryAxis(FXCollections.observableArrayList(alphabet)),
                new NumberAxis(0, 200, 20)
        );
        barChart.getData().add(series);
        barChart.setLegendVisible(false);
        barChart.setPrefSize(700, 500);
        barChart.getStyleClass().add(CHART_STYLE);

        StackPane layout = new StackPane(new Group(barChart));
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 800, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(CSS);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private static XYChart.Data<String, Number> createData(String s) {
        XYChart.Data<String, Number> data =  new XYChart.Data<>(
                s,
                ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(
                        50, 200
                )
        );

        Label label = new Label(
                "%s : %s".formatted(
                        data.getXValue(), data.getYValue()
                )
        );
        label.getStyleClass().add(DATA_LABEL_STYLE);

        data.setNode(new StackPane(label));

        return data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}

